# How to generate a text file from a String for download in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm building a website using Rails and I have a Model with some text type value store in MySQL database, I need to provide a download link for my users to download a "*.txt" file which contains those texts.

what I've tried is to use `render :text => my_text`  but it's kind of ugly and the browser can't start a download .

Not I'm trying to use CarrierWave and mount a output_file to my model , I want to build a method to generate a file from its text value. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
send_data 'text to send', :filename => 'some.txt'
```

[Documentation Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data)

Comment: And how can we make a link to in in the view?